# TypeScript - inferring or declaring Pick type as a functions return value

Tags: typescript

Considering the following simplified function, which accepts an object and a property of that object, and returns a clone of that object with only the specified property:

```
export function clonePick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: K) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => k === prop)
  return keys.reduce(
    (clone: any, key: string) => {
      return { ...clone, [key]: obj[key as keyof T] };
    },
    {}
  );
}
```

This is essentially identical behavior to Pick except for a value instead of a type, and so it's return type *could* be expressed as:

```
Pick<T, prop>
```

Except the above is not valid typescript. However, we can know the value of prop *well* before runtime when calling the function:

```
interface ITest {
  numProp: number;
  strProp: string;
}

const test = { numProp: 1, strProp: '1' }; // <-- type is ITest

const testClone = clonePick(test, 'numProp') // <-- type is any
```

I can easily declare this explicitly:

```
const testClone: Pick<ITest, 'numProp'> = clonePick(test, 'numProp')
```

But it would be a lot more maintainable if I could include that behavior as part of the above function. Is this possible? Preferably it can work with an array of properties as well as a single prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get the compiler to infer that complicated `reduce` call to a `Pick`, it won't even și it for simpler things such as `{ [prop]: obj[prop] }`. Your best option is to use an annotation for the return type of the function.

```
export function clonePick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: K): Pick<T,K> {

  return { [prop]: obj[prop] } as any;
}


interface ITest {
  numProp: number;
  strProp: string;
}

const test = { numProp: 1, strProp: '1' }; // <-- type is ITest

const testClone = clonePick(test, 'numProp') // 

testClone.numProp
testClone.strProp // err
```

Comment: I assumed that signature would not work with an array of props but TypeScript smartly infers this as `"numProp" | "strProp"`. This is the exact behavior I needed!